# Деление строки

Tags: php

Нужно вот такую строку `"Время//нАЗВАНИЕ**Статья"` разбить на 3 переменные в первой чтоб хранилось время во второй название статьи и сама статья значки `//` и `**` используются как разделители? Подскажите, как разбить?

Comment: один тип разделитей не хотете сделать? будет сильно проще

Answer (score 2):

А вообще можно так:

```
$str = 'Время//нАЗВАНИЕ**Статья';
list($time, $name, $text) = explode('//', str_replace('**', '//', $str), 3);
```

Comment: интересно, а если в статье встретится ** или // ??? что произойдет?

Comment: Обновил, теперь - ничего)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_split('@//|\*\*@', $string, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1

```
$str = 'Время//нАЗВАНИЕ**Статья';
list($time, $tmp) = explode('//', $str, 2);
list($name, $text) = explode('**', $tmp, 2);
unset( $tmp );
```

Тут лишняя переменная

Вариант 2

```
if(preg_match('@^(.*)//(.*)\*\*(.*)@n', $str, $match)) {
    list( $time, $name, $text) = list( $match[1], $match[2], $match[3] );
}
```

Тут могут быть странности, нужно смотреть на данные

Comment: > `list( $time, $name, $text) = list( $match[1], $match[2], $match[3] );`

    list(, $time, $name, $text) = $match;